# Changing strings in Hopper Disassembler

Tags: patch-reversing, hopper

I am currently learning and I wanted to ask, how can I change a text (string) from inside an app I am reversing? For example "To begin, please login". I have found the XREF to the string location but I don't know how to change it. I am using Hopper Disassembler on mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify strings or other bytes within the hex editor (⇧⌘H) or click on the hex edit panel.

[image: hexedit panel]

Then modify whatever you want

[image: edit bytes]
You'll need to write a new executable back (⇧⌘E) if you want to save it. Also, be aware that if it is a signed binary, you will need to remove any code signature or resign it as the binary won't match the signature after a change.

Comment: @cimmaron could you please explain with screen shots.

Comment: Is it the string length limited?